# How do I view php source code in php?

Tags: php, jquery, viewer

I want to output some php code with php, but I can't seem to ge get the right format.

My function to view the Code is this:

```
public function openFile($path, $save = false)
    {
    if($save == true) $filename = basename($path); else $filename = "tmp/".substr(hash("sha256", time()), 8, 25).".tmp";//Datei speichern
    #$fp = fopen($filename, "wr");
    $url = "ftp://".$this->username.":".$this->password."@".$this->host.":".$this->port.$path;
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    #curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/plain;"));
    #curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    $result = curl_exec($handle);
    $info = curl_getinfo ($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
    header("Content-Type: text/plain;");
    echo htmlentities($result);
    return [$result, $info];
    }
```

i have a "ajaxActions.php" where I handle all the actions:

```
<?php
require_once('../classes/ftp.class.php');
$webftp = new FTP("127.0.0.1", 21, "root", "123", false, true);


if(!empty($_REQUEST["action"]) && !empty($_REQUEST["path"]))
    {
    switch ($_REQUEST["action"])
        {
        case "getDirs":
            $dirs = $webftp->listDirectory($_REQUEST["path"]);
            echo "<tr data-type=\"dir\">";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td><a onClick=\"dirUp();\" href=\"#\">..</a></td>";
            echo "<td>".$webftp->getSize("..")."</td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "<td></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            foreach ($dirs as $dir)
                {
                // Überprüfen ob der Pfad ein Verzeichnis ist, falls ja, kann man es betreten ansonsten wird die Datei angezeigt
                if($webftp->ftpIsDir($dir)==true) $data = "folder-close"; else $data = "file";

                $aTag = "<a onClick=\"reloadTable('".$dir."');\" href=\"#\">".$dir."</a>";
                if($data == "file") $aTag = "<a onClick=\"openFile('".$dir."');\" href=\"#\">".$dir."</a>";
                echo "<tr data-type=\"".$data."\">";
                echo "<td><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-".$data."\"></i></td>";
                echo "<td>".$aTag."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$webftp->getSize($dir)."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($data == "file" ? '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>' : '')."<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></i><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save\"></i><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></i></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
            break;

        case "dirUp":
            $webftp->dirUp();
            break;

        case "openFile":
            $webftp->openFile($_REQUEST["path"]);
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

on my index.php i parse the code via jQuery:

```
function openFile(path) {
  $.get("lib/includes/ajaxActions.php?action=openFile&path=" + path, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#editor').html(data);
    $('#sourceCode').modal('show')
  });
}
```

the console.log() returns the right code, but on the div#editor is no syntax, all the breaks are gone.

output:
console.log():

```
&lt;?php

    class FTP  {
    private $host = &quot;&quot;;
    private $port = &quot;&quot;;
    private $username = &quot;&quot;;
    private $password = &quot;&quot;;
    private $passive = false;
    private $connection = false;
    private $ssl = false;
    private $dir = false;


    public function __construct($host, $port = 21, $username, $password, $ssl = false, $passive = false)
        {
        if ( !extension_loaded('ftp') )
            {
            throw new Exception('FTP extension is not loaded!');
            }
        $this-&gt;host = $host;
        $this-&gt;port = $port;
        $this-&gt;username = $username;
        $this-&gt;password = $password;
        $this-&gt;ssl = $ssl;
        $this-&gt;passive = $passive;

        $this-&gt;connect($this-&gt;host, $this-&gt;port, $this-&gt;ssl, 90);
        $this-&gt;login($this-&gt;username, $this-&gt;password);
        }
```

div#editor:

```
<?php class FTP { private $host = ""; private $port = ""; private $username = ""; private $password = ""; private $passive = false; private $connection = false; private $ssl = false; private $dir = false; public function __construct($host, $port = 21, $username, $password, $ssl = false, $passive = false) { if ( !extension_loaded('ftp') ) { throw new Exception('FTP extension is not loaded!'); } $this->host = $host; $this->port = $port; $this->username = $username; $this->password = $password; $this->ssl = $ssl; $this->passive = $passive; $this->connect($this->host, $this->port, $this->ssl, 90); $this->login($this->username, $this->password); } public function connect($host ,$port = 21, $ssl = false, $timeout = 90) { if ($ssl) { $this->connection = ftp_ssl_connect($host, $port, $timeout); } else { $this->connection = ftp_connect($host, $port, $timeout); } if ($this->connection == null) { throw new Exception('Unable to connect'); } else { return $this; } }
```

Comment: Use `nl2br` to add `<br>` markup before all the line breaks.

Comment: `echo nl2br(htmlentities($result));` http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Why not use [highlight_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) or [highlight_string()](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
echo htmlentities($result);
```

to:

```
echo '<code>' . nl2br(htmlentities($result)) . '</code>';
```

`nl2br` adds `<br>` markup before all the newlines. And adding `<code>` should maintain the formatting of the code. Although I'm not sure you can depend on <kbd>Tab</kbd> lining up properly -- the browser's tab stops may be different from your IDE's.

Comment: but what is with tabs? All tabs rendered as one empty character

Comment: I don't know what ace is.

Comment: look at this: http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about i figured out the problem. I can't set the text with $('#editor').html(data);

Answer (score 0):

The output string that you want to render has to be properly escaped. This means replacing all your "<" and ">" and possibly other chars as well with their html corespondents.
Long story short, instead of using echo that many times, assign all that text to a `$var` and do `echo htmlentities($var);`. For PHP tags, i think you have to manually replace the "<" and ">" with their urlEncoded values.
I hope it has been of at least some help.

Comment: the Browser rendered "&lt;" to "<" there is not the problem, i mean the br's :)

Comment: He's using `echo htmlentities($result)` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:
my javascript code looks like this:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/php");
editor.setOptions({
    maxLines: 50
});

function openFile(path) {
    $.get("lib/includes/ajaxActions.php?action=openFile&path=" + path, function(data) {
        editor.setValue(data);
        $('#sourceCode').modal('show')
    });
}
```

my phpcode:

```
public function openFile($path, $save = false)
        {
        if($save == true) $filename = basename($path); else $filename = "tmp/".substr(hash("sha256", time()), 8, 25).".tmp";//Datei speichern
        #$fp = fopen($filename, "wr");
        $url = "ftp://".$this->username.":".$this->password."@".$this->host.":".$this->port.$path;
        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        #curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/plain;"));
        #curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        $result = curl_exec($handle);
        $info = curl_getinfo ($handle);
        curl_close($handle);
        #header("Content-Type: text/plain;");
        echo $result;
        return [$result, $info];
        }
```